# How to override Module Frontend Editing Page

Tags: module, front-end, module-params, editing

I'm trying to override Module Front End Editing Page. I tried to copy this folder [root]/layouts/joomla/edit to [root]/templates/template_name/html/layouts/joomla/edit but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the wrong folder, this is the correct one : /root/components/com_config/view/modules